# Strange Pattern in Cycles Renders Despite Shade Smooth and Auto Smooth

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, smooth

I've been encountering an issue when rendering a metallic object in Blender Cycles, where a strange pattern appears on the reflection of the model. I've tried using shade smooth, auto smooth, and adjusting normals, but these are making any difference. Here's a screenshot of the issue:

[image]

Here part of the mesh (the center is blurred because it is under NDA):

[image]

and here are my shader nodes:

[image]

Has anyone faced a similar problem with metallic materials, or can anyone offer any guidance on how to resolve this issue? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello could you please share your object or at least a part of it?

Comment: I can show you the only part of the mesh

Comment: If you're using a Normal Map node, try decreasing the strength

Comment: Just cut off a small part of the mesh and share it

Comment: here is a cut:
https://edgardberendsen.com/public/bottle_cap.001.fbx

Comment: This is just bad topology, also in file you've provided you have 1 million faces just for the outer part of the cap that is insane. Notice how on places where there are a lot of edges https://imgur.com/UtxjpYm are the same place where you have shading artifacts https://imgur.com/q5qF76O. You will need to make it again, if you can't use normal map for whatever is on top of cap then make nice cap with even faces and then sculpt logo on top and bake high to low.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, there is too much geometry which make creases, du to their geometry.

So decimating can be a way to do it. Won't be a perfect result, but it makes most of the issue disappear:

[image]

In edit mode, select all (except a special part but see below) and use the menu "Mesh/Clean up/Decimate Geometry".
Then in the operator panel bring the ratio down to 0.25 (or make some tests for other values).

[image]

Special part: I think you've cutted the top part (NDA, etc.). So there is a special case for the faces at the cut.

Before decimating, in face selection mode, use "Select Sharp Edges" from the "Select" menu (edit mode), invert the selection then decimate.

An example file but decimated twice at 0.25 as if not it was too big to upload here:

[image]